# 'Build' is not displayed in iTunes Connect using Xcode 8

Tags: app-store, submit

'Build' is not displayed in iTunes Connect using Xcode 8

Help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E659m.png)

Answer (score 0):

After submitting app on App store they will take time 30-40 min processing.
Please wait 30-40 min then you can see "+" to add build. on same page

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I was waiting for 3 days. But no "+"

Comment: I am very disappointed about this problem. I was tried to submit using Xcode and ApplicationLoader.

Comment: But unfortunately, not result yet

Answer (score 0):

Once you uploaded your build, it's getting processed in iTunes Connect. To check the current status go to My Apps > App Name > Activity > All Builds

[image]

If it's not there, there's usually an error with your build and you should already gotten an email from Apple. ("Build rejected/There is a problem with your build")

After the build got processed, you will see a small "+" icon next to the build and will get a popup showing you the build(s)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't see "Select a build before you submit your app"

Comment: Yeah, I have checked that again. But unfortunately I can't see this item.

Comment: If the build is not in the Activity > All Builds tab (upper screen), it didn't get uploaded. Try it again and make sure you have access to the developer email to see if you get any errors from Apple

Comment: I was tried to submit the app using Xcode and ApplicaitonLoader too.

Comment: But unfortunately, not result in Build yet

Comment: How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please help me.